# Joomla 3. Как запретить OpenSearch скачивать xml-файл?

Tags: joomla3

В стандартном поиске **Joomla** есть функция включения **OpenSearch**, которая на каждой странице в `<head>` подставляет `link` на соответствующий файл `xml` вида:

```
<link href="http://site.name/component/search/?id=45&amp;Itemid=104&amp;format=opensearch" rel="search" title="title" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />
```

Если перейти по этой ссылке, то скачается `xml` с описанием **OpenSearch**.

В модуле поиска я эту функцию отключил, теперь подобных ссылок в `<head>` нет. Но! Если напрямую перейти , например по ссылке `http://site.name/component/search/?format=opensearch`, то все равно скачивается тот же самый файлик `xml`.

Вопрос. Как это вообще работает? Где этот файл формируется? И как заставить Joomla **не** предлагать этот файл скачивать?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, не нашел ничего лучше, чем прямо в коде компонента заглушить вызов формирования этих файликов:

```
// components/com_search/views/search/view.opensearch.php
class SearchViewSearch extends JViewLegacy
{
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        // Заглушка для всех файлов описаний OpenSearch
        header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" );
        exit();
        ...
    }
}
```

Конечно, не очень комильфо... но другого решения я не нашел.
v
Теперь при переходе по ссылке просто получаем **HTTP**-код `404`.